# When should I use the infinite `to´ at the end of a sentence?

Tags: to-infinitive

When should I use the infinitive "to" at the end of a sentence? For example:

> My father said that I have to clean the bathroom, but I don't want to.

Or can I just say

> My father said that I have to clean the bathroom, but I don't want.

Feel free for giving some examples.

Comment: No you can't. It leaves the sentence hanging in the air. In short, it's wrong. **but I don't want to.** is a short form of saying **but I don't want to clean the bathroom**. The **to** is essential to the meaning.

Comment: Are you still around? I have answered the question **in depth**.

Answer (score 2):

This phenomenon is technically called **stranding**. There are only a handful of words that can be stranded in English, such as the auxiliaries and the prepositions:

> **Auxiliary stranding:** 
> *He can talk to her but I can't*
>
> **Preposition straining**
>
> *What are you talking about?*

The infinitive marker "to" can also be stranded, as your example suggests. However, a lexical verb such as "want" cannot be stranded. Therefore, the second sentence is ungrammatical:

> My father said that I have to clean the bathroom, but I don't want  <sup>UNGRAMMATICAL</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Because rules of English grammar were derived by [linguistic prescription](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription) from classical language grammar, at one time it was stated that one should not end a sentence with a preposition nor should one [split an infinitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_infinitive).

However, [descriptive linguistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_description) finds acceptable, colloquial English often omits words and splits infinitives with impunity. When a parent commands a child to go to bed, a response of, "I don't want to!" is just as clear as, and more pithy, than, "I don't want to go to bed!". The phrase, "go to bed," is understood **in context**. However, the final "to" is **never** omitted.

Comment: True. But the OP is asking about omitting the final "to".

Comment: And, the "to" in "I don't want to" is not a preposition, but a subordinator, a special marker for VPs of infinitival clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyse the two versions separately.

> My father said that I have to clean the bathroom, but I don't want.

The problem with this sentence is that **want** is a *verb of incomplete predication* in this sentence and such verbs demand a *subject complement* or an *object complement* to make a complete sentence. Since such isn't the case with this sentence, it is grammatically incorrect.

> My father said that I have to clean the bathroom, but I don't **want to** [clean the bathroom.]

In this sentence **want** is a *transitive verb*, and because transitive verbs demand an *object*, the above sentence is a grammatically correct sentence. The *object* of the sentence is the implied infinitive phrase *to clean the bathroom* (It's not incorrect to leave out part of a sentence like this; this is called *ellipsis* in grammar.)

Therefore, this version of the sentence is the correct one.

Comment: The verb is not "want to", but just "want". The "to" is a subordinator, a special marker for VPs of infinitival clauses. Here, the head of the VP is missing but understood as "clean the bathroom". Note that clauses do not function as objects, so it's wrong to say that "clean the bathroom" is object.

Comment: @BillJ: Thank you. I must have been groggy when I said _want to_ is a prepositional verb. _to_ is of course the infinitive marker here. Rest, I preferred to answer in the light of the traditional grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better example is:

> Where are you headed to?

or

> I don't know who to give this to.

That is very understandable English. You probably wouldn't use it in more elevated settings though.

True there is a difference between verbal phrases that use a verb and elliptical replies and true prepositions at the end of a sentence.
Verbal phrases are like:

speak up
speak on
speak about
speak over

Comment: Hello Hoppin Jane and welcome to ELL! Please note that if you want to break a line, you either need to hit Enter *twice*, or put two spaces at the end of the line. Just one "Enter" does nothing.

Comment: "Where are you headed" is far more common than with the "to".  Unless you're from Somerset.

Comment: Both your "to"s actually indicate direction, and are not the same as the "to" in "want to".

Answer (score 0):

Certain verbs (the ones below) do not require repetition of the main clause or object after them and the "to" can be left at the end of the sentence. The first verb in the utterance is an action verb and the second before "to" is one of the ones below. What governs the "to" are certain verbs:

**LIKE**
You can come with us if **you'd like to**. [no need to repeat *come with us*]

**WANT**
I like to play tennis but I am not sure **I want to**. [no need to repeat *play tennis*]

**PREFER**
He'd love to listen to your music but I'd **prefer not to**. [no need to *repeat listen to the music*].

**WISH**
They can come along with us if **they wish to**. [no need to repeat *come along with us*]

**HATE**
She goes to the movies every night but **I'd hate to**. [no need to repeat *go to the movies every night.*

**DISLIKE**
He makes dinner every night but **I'd dislike to**. [no need to repeat make *dinner every night*.

**DESIRE**
I see no reason you shouldn't leave home if **you desire to**. [no need to repeat *leave home*]

[I may have missed one or two but these are the main ones. These are all spoken forms and very much used in English.]

Be aware that in conversations, **people may already know what the discussion is about** so you will get a lot of utterances like these without the main action verb as that verb will have been spoken by the other person:

- I've **love to**.
- They'd really **hate to**.
- We'd maybe **want to**.
- He's really **like to** but he can't.

Mastering these types of utterances is required to have an advanced level of spoken English. So I advise practicing them even if you don't want to. :)